# CSS line inside a container

Tags: html, css

Imagine having a box

```
a          b
 ----------
|          |
|          |
c----------d
```

The box have point a,b,c and d. I need to have a line from point b to point c, and I will have my data lets say `100%` in point a and point d.

is this possible? I tried to look using `fr` but I still have the problem of drawing a line

Comment: Vian, you can make this work using an svg. It will be responsive based on the width and height of the container. You can style the path element to have the proper color and stroke thickness. If that sounds like what you need, say so and I'll add an answer with code for that solution.

Comment: That might work. Please add this answer, I think this is the better option

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make some calculations to connect a line perfectly...

```css
.test{
  width:50vw;
  height:40vw;
  border:2px solid #000;
  position:relative;
}
.test::after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  /*get the slope (y/x)*/
  /* here 40/50 = 4/5 ... arctan(4/5) = 0.67 radian  */
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%) rotate(-0.67rad);
  height:2px;
  /* calculate the width of the line (width^2 + height^2)^(1/2) */
  /* width = 64.0312423743 */
  width:64vw;
  background:#000;
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: This is good, but this will not be mobile responsive since the width is static

Comment: It could be if you can define your dimensions in vw and vh...

Comment: You got the idea, you can make a javascript code to change the line rotation angle and width..

Comment: I edited the code btw, it's now in terms of vw instead of px